# How to get the same result every time when allocating values following a specific distribution

Tags: r, random-seed

My data consists of postal codes and hospitals. Many records have a missing hospital and I want to allocate the hospital to this record following the distribution of all records in the postal code. Let's say that in Postcal code 2211 the distribution of hospitals A and B is 0.3 vs. 0.7. The records with missing hospitals in this Postcal code needs to follow the same distribution and needs to get the same results every time I run the code.

I already tried:

```
sample(c("A","B"), nrow(df), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3,0.7))
```

This gave the desired result, but when I run the code again, the result on record level is different. I read about set.seed() but that doesn't give the same output.

Some of my data:

```
  postal code hospital daydate
1         2211       NA       0
2         2211       NA       6
3         2211       NA       8
4         2211       NA      15
5         2211       NA      18
6         2211       NA      18
7         2211       NA      25
8         2211       NA      30
9         2211       NA      51
10        2211       NA      55
11        2211       NA      58
12        2211       NA      59
13        2211       NA      61
14        2211       NA      61
15        2211       NA      64
16        2211       NA      66
17        2211       NA      68
18        2211       NA      69
```

There are 18 records in this example so 13 records needs to get hospital A and 5 records needs to get hospital B. And for example record 10 always needs to be A and not the second time B.

I hope my question is clear (first time I asked a question here) and that someone can help me out! Thank you in advance!

Comment: addition: I ordered my data on daydate (day of the year of a date in my data) so everytime the order of the records is the same. I thought that it could help in the solution

Comment: Are you sure you are using `set.seed()` right? It works for me.

Comment: I did not use it right. The answer of GKi helped me out. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set.seed` should be the solution:

```
set.seed(0)
s1 <- sample(c("A","B"), 18, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3,0.7))
set.seed(0)
s2 <- sample(c("A","B"), 18, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3,0.7))
identical(s1, s2)
#[1] TRUE
```